# MATLAB and DataFrame

Tags: matlab, dataframe

Is anyone using the DataFrame package (https://github.com/rothnic/DataFrame)?

I use it because older MATLAB can also use it. However, I just have very basic question:

1. How to change value in the DataFrame?
   In MATLAB's table function, it is straightforward to do it. For example, `t{1,{'prior'}} = {'a = 2000'}`, where `t` is a table and I assign a cell to it. I cannot figure out how to do it in DataFrame package.
2. The DataFrame author seems not maintaining it anymore(?). I hope someone could give more examples of its methods in DataFrame.

Thanks!